# Skype call via Android intent results in group conversation instead of call

Tags: android, skype

The below code used to work fine:

```
Uri skypeUri = Uri.parse("skype:<username injected>?call&video=true");
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, skypeUri);
this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

A user would click a button on my app and get re-directed to Skype to place a call with a user:

[image]

Recently, this code stopped working. Instead the user still gets redirected to Skype, but when they start the call there's no ringing on their end and the receiver of the 'call' sees this:

[image]

Based on [Skype docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_androidapps?redirectedfrom=MSDN) my code is still correct, but something must have changed. I have ran my app in multiple Android devices and observe the same issue.

Comment: I use the same URI and it works. Did you try calling to a different device? May be related to the receiving device?